# solving a simple polynomial equation?

Tags: polynomials

I am looking for a solution to an equation of the form $a x^4 + b x + c = 0$.

(I need the positive solutions only, but I can filter the negative ones out, if I get the four solutions for the above.)

Is there a general way to derive a solution for this equation?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the field of real numbers this equation need not have any solutions, e.g. for $(a,b,c)=(1,0,1)$ we have $x^4+1=0$, which clearly has no real solutions. 
Over the complex numbers all four solutions can be written down by [Ferrari-Cardano's formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ferrari%27s_Method).